# setting context with list of objects as prameters in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I have a list of values each having another KEY value corresponding to it, when i present this list to user, user has to select a value and agent has to call an external api with selected value's KEY. how can i achieve this in dialogflow?

I tried to send the entire key value pair in the context and access it in the next intent but for some reason when i set a list(array) to context parameters dialogflow simply ignoring the fulfillment response.

What is happening here and is there any good way to achieve this? I am trying to develop a food ordering chatbot where the category of items in menu is presented and list items in that menu will fetched when user selects a category, this menu is not static thats why i am using api calls to get the dynamic menu.

```
function newOrder(agent)
{

  var categories = []
  var cat_parameters = {}
  var catarray = []
  const conv = agent.conv();
  //conv.ask('sure, select a category to order');
  agent.add('select a category to order');
  return  getAllCategories().then((result)=>{

    for(let i=0; i< result.restuarantMenuList.length; i++)
    {
      try{
        var name = result.restuarantMenuList[i].Name;
        var catid = result.restuarantMenuList[i].Id;
        categories.push(name)
        //categories.name = catid
        cat_parameters['id'] = catid;
        cat_parameters['name'] = name
        catarray.push(cat_parameters)
      }catch(ex)
      {
        agent.add('trouble getting the list please try again later')
      }
    }
    agent.context.set({
      name: 'categorynames',
      lifespan: 5,
      parameters: catarray, // if i omit this line, the reponse is the fultillment response with categories names, if i keep this line the reponse is fetching from default static console one.
    })
    return agent.add('\n'+categories.toString())

  })

  function selectedCategory(agent)
  {
    //agent.add('category items should be fetched and displayed here');
    var cat = agent.parameters.category
    const categories = agent.context.get('categorynames')

    const cat_ob = categories.parameters.cat_parameters

    // use the key in the catarray with the parameter cat to call the external API
    agent.add('you have selected '+ cat );
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary issue is that the context `parameters` must be an object, it cannot be an array.

So when you save it, you can do something like

```
parameters: {
  "cat_parameters": catarray
}
```

and when you deal with it when you get the reply, you can get the array back with

```
let catarray = categories.parameters.cat_parameters;
```

(There are some other syntax and scoping issues with your code, but this seems like it is the data availability issue you're having.)

Comment: thank you, i resolved the issue exactly like you said, it was a silly mistake, i am so embarrassed. i am not just new to dialogflow, i am new to javascript and node js as well(I have Java background). i am picking up slowly, thank you for not ignoring this stupid and dumb question from a newbie

Comment: Glad you solved the problem! If the answer helped, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated. Don't be embarrassed by an error like this - it is an easy one to miss, and sometimes it helps to talk out the problem with someone else. Hopefully by sharing your question here, you've helped someone else in the future who made the same mistake.